# Backbone.js multi level ul

Tags: model, backbone.js, nested, html-lists

I'm beginning  a backbone project and I figured I'd start with the menu system.
My menu is based on a multi level ul.  So basically there are nested uls in side some of the lis

I'm wondering how I would create a model/collection for that. And for that matter how I would do the view. I've seen people creating views with a tag type of li.  But I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am personally a fan of using the collection view and an item view (prevents rerendering the whole list)

```
AutoFiler.Views.Messages = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderItem');
    this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);
    this.collection.bind('add', this.renderItem);
    this.collection.bind('remove', this.render);
},
render: function () {
    this.el.empty();
    this.collection.each(this.renderItem);
    return this;
},
renderItem: function (item) {
    var viewC = new AutoFiler.Views.Message({ model: item });
    this.el.append(viewC.render().el);
}
});
AutoFiler.Views.Message = Backbone.View.extend({
   template: _.template($("#Message-template").html()),
   tagName: "li",
   initialize: function () {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
   },
   render: function () {
     $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
     return this;
   }
});

<script id="Message-template" type="text/template">
    <div>{{ Subject }}</div>
</script>

<ul id="Messages"> 

</ul>
```

gives you

```
<ul id="Messages"> 
    <li><div>Subject A</div></li>
    <li><div>Subject B</div></li>
</ul>
```

which you could you could nest by creating a collection of lists (collections of collections)

or you can just style using a class name and depth

http://jsfiddle.net/3HGuf/

like that

I think it makes the code a little easier to read

Comment: Thank you for that example. regrettably my brain has just been ripped out and stomped on by an nhibernate mapping issue and I'm having a bit of trouble focusing.  Could you elaborate on the collection of collections?  would my model have a collection property of something like that? and would I then have to recurse through the views to get it all out there?  I can't do the css trick as I have a plug in that is expecting nested lists.  Thanks for your help